# Flask - Calling and stopping functions via webpage (raspberry pi)

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to setup a simple flask webpage to control a 3d Xmas Tree running on a raspberry pi. I've posted the code for the app and the template below. So far it works in that I can run a single function, such as Flicker and then perform either the Reset or Off functions. However, I am not able to call other functions following that. And if I run Flicker and then Random or All Flash they kind of blend together. My goal is to be able to cleanly stop GPIO output via the reset or off functions and call each respective function via the webpage's buttons or links.

app2.py

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import random
from random import randint
from gpiozero.tools import random_values
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from gpiozero import LEDBoard
from time import sleep
from signal import pause

app = Flask(__name__)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
tree = LEDBoard(*range(2,28),pwm=True)

@app.route("/")
def home2():
    return render_template("home2.html")
    
@app.route("/flicker/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def flicker():
#    GPIO.cleanup()
    for led in tree:
        led.source_delay = random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)
        led.source = random_values()
        sleep(1)
    pause()
    return render_template("home2.html")

@app.route("/randomOnOff/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def randomOnOff():
    while True:
        for led in tree:
            s = randint(0,1)
            if (s==1):
                    led.on()
            else:
                    led.off()
        sleep(1)
    return render_template("home2.html")
    
@app.route("/allFlash/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def allFlash():
    while True:
        tree.on()
        sleep(1)
        tree.off()
        sleep(1)
    return render_template("home2.html")
    
@app.route("/upAndDown/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upAndDown():
    while True:
        tree.off()
        order = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,0]
        for item in order:
                tree[item].on()
                sleep(0.1)
        order.reverse()
        sleep(0.5)
        for item in order:
                tree[item].off()
                sleep(0.1)
    return render_template("home2.html")

@app.route("/reset/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def tree_reset():
    GPIO.cleanup()
    return render_template("home2.html")
    
@app.route("/off/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def tree_off():
    tree.off()
    return render_template("home2.html")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Raspberry Pi Xmas Tree</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">Raspberry Pi Christmas Tree</h1>
        <strong><nav>
        <a href="/" class="button">Home</a>  
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <ul class="menu">
        <form action="/flicker/" method="post">
            <button name="flicker" type="submit">Flicker Lights</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/randomOnOff/" method="post">
            <button name="randomOnOff" type="submit">Random Lights</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/allFlash/" method="post">
            <button name="allFlash" type="submit">Flash All Lights</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/upAndDown/" method="post">
            <button name="upAndDown" type="submit">Up and Down</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/reset/" method="post">
            <button name="reset" type="submit">Reset</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/off/" method="post">
            <button name="off" type="submit">Turn Off</button>
        </form>
        </ul>
        </nav></strong>
      </div>
    </header>
    
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

 </body>
</html>
```

I'm a little lost on getting this working as intended. I've read into similar posts related to threading and multi-threading, but I don't think that is the issue. I am not sure if I am GETting and POSTing the calls incorrectly. I've read similar posts using ajax in the template, but I don't think that is an issue either as this does *work* but possibly not efficiently.

Any help, insight, or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You should not have your tree control functions within your handlers.  You should create a separate tree controller task that does the while true loop, and it should have a run mode table in it that the handlers can modify through, say, a message queue.

Comment: Appreciate the input @RufusVS - can you help me understand what the run mode table might be like, I'm not too familiar. Is that similar to what the below poster did in the TreeState class?

Comment: When I say "Run Mode" I mean essentially the same TreeState is used for in @ybermans answer.  The tree task just keeps looping, and manipulating the lights according to its current mode or state.   ybermans program looks like it should be a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I don't have your setup so I couldn't test fully. But I think you want a background loop, and use global state to manage interaction with tree (since there is physically one tree.)

```py
from enum import Enum
from random import randint, uniform
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from gpiozero import LEDBoard
from gpiozero.tools import random_values
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class TreeState(Enum):
    OFF = 1
    FLICKER = 2
    RANDOM_ON_OFF = 3
    ALL_FLASH = 4
    UP_AND_DOWN = 5
    TERMINATE = 6


def main_loop():
    while True:
        if state == TreeState.TERMINATE:
            tree.off()
            GPIO.cleanup()
            quit()

        if state == TreeState.ALL_FLASH:
            tree.on()
            sleep(1)
            tree.off()
            # to prevent you could set looping state = TreeState.OFF
            # state = TreeState.OFF

        if state == TreeState.RANDOM_ON_OFF:
            tree.off()
            for led in tree:
                s = randint(0,1)
                if s == 1:
                    led.on()
                else:
                    led.off()
            # state = TreeState.OFF

        if state == TreeState.UP_AND_DOWN:
            tree.off()
            order = list(range(1, 25)) + [0] 
            for item in order:
                    tree[item].on()
                    sleep(0.1)
            order.reverse()
            sleep(0.5)
            for item in order:
                    tree[item].off()
                    sleep(0.1)
            # state = TreeState.OFF

        # I have been unable to test this        
        if state == TreeState.FLICKER:
            for led in tree:
                led.source_delay = random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)
                led.source = random_values()
            sleep(1)

        # after a second repeat the loop
        sleep(1)

app = Flask(__name__)
state = TreeState.OFF
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
tree = LEDBoard(*range(2, 28), pwm=True)


@app.route("/")
def home2():
    return render_template("home2.html", state=str(state))

# post-redirect-get
@app.route("/setState/<new_state>", methods=["POST"])
def setState(new_state):
    new_state = TreeState[new_state]
    global state
    state = new_state
    return redirect(url_for('home2'))

  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(name="backgroundLoop", target=main_loop).start()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Note new POST endpoints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Raspberry Pi Xmas Tree</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">Raspberry Pi Christmas Tree</h1>
        <h2 class="status">The tree is {{state}}</h2>
        <strong><nav>
        <a href="/" class="button">Home</a>  
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <ul class="menu">
        <form action="/setState/FLICKER" method="post">
            <button name="flicker" type="submit">Flicker Lights</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/setState/RANDOM_ON_OFF" method="post">
            <button name="randomOnOff" type="submit">Random Lights</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/setState/ALL_FLASH" method="post">
            <button name="allFlash" type="submit">Flash All Lights</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/setState/UP_AND_DOWN" method="post">
            <button name="upAndDown" type="submit">Up and Down</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/setState/OFF" method="post">
            <button name="reset" type="submit">Reset</button>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <form action="/setState/TERMINATE" method="post">
            <button name="off" type="submit">Shut down server</button>
        </form>
        </ul>
        </nav></strong>
      </div>
    </header>
    
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That handles each tree function much more cleanly. And Flicker works as well. The Off/Terminate states work, but when I then call another function it does not output to GPIO. I'll have to look into cleanly shutting down GPIO outputs and being able to start them again. Appreciate the input

Comment: After terminating the program should quit. Does going between the the other states work?

Comment: Going between states does work, but the GPIO outputs overlap. If I click Flicker and then Up and Down it combines the output to the GPIO so it is toggling the LEDs in an up and down pattern and also flickering all LEDs

Comment: You should not have overlaps between states, because state should have only one value at any given time.  One thing you might want to do is give the tree loop its own copy of the state, so you can make sure state changes are always recognized at the top of the loop.  (Or as I alluded to in my comment, "send" state changes to the tree task through a queue, instead of depending on a global variable, which is not usually a good practice.)